# Unable to succesfully create a std::list of unique objects

Tags: c++, class, opengl, pointers, linked-list

I have an OpenGL GLUT-based (yes, I know, GLUT is ancient) C++ program that alternatingly prints out a blue rectangle and a red square, located at the point in the GLUT window where the user clicks the mouse. This is working fine.

I encountered a mind-boggling amount of trouble, however, when I attempted to modify the above program so that the aforementioned shapes REMAIN on the canvas after their initial animation.

I have created a Shape class which holds such information as the number of vertices, color, coordinates, etc. The class seems fully functional when the program is only drawing one shape at a time.

In order to solve the multiple-shapes-at-once problem, I created a `std::list<Shape>` linked list. However, when I iterate through the linked list via the `std::list<Shape>::iterator` mechanism, the objects appear to be tied together in memory. That is, iteration yields the exact same shape object, coordinates and all, for each index in the Linked List.

I have tried the following solutions:

making the linked list a `std::list<Shape*>` instead of a `std::list<Shape>`,

- utilizing the heap for object allocation via `Shape* my_shape = new Shape(params)`,
- and combining the the two above methods.

Here is my `void display()` GLUT function, along with the relevant global variables AND the class definition/declaration:

```
class Shape
{

public:
    Shape();
    Shape(int, double[], int[]);
    int type; //0 = rectangle, 1 = circle, 2 = triangle
    int numVertices; //stores total number of vertices in the 2D object.
    double* vertexArray; //a dynamic array that stores each vertex's (x, y)-coordinates in alternating successive indices
    int* rgb; //an array that contains the 3 rgb values s.t. rgb = {r, g, b}
    double* center; //an array that contains the (x, y)-coordinates of the shape's center on the 2d plane.
    int velocity[2]; //a array of size 2 that holds the object's x-velocity in index 0 and the object's y-velocity in index 1

};

    //default Shape constructor
Shape::Shape()
{

}

//Shape constructor 
Shape::Shape(int shapeType, double vertices[], int color[]) //constructor for creating a stationary 2D shape
{
    type = shapeType;

    if (shapeType!=1) //as long as shape is NOT a circle, interpret the second constructor parameter as a list of vertices 
    {
        vertexArray = vertices;
    }

    rgb = color;

    if (shapeType==0) //shape is a rectangle
    {
        numVertices = 4;
    }
    else if(shapeType==1) //shape is a circle
    {
        //shape is a circle, therefore the second array param is in fact an array of size 2 containing the (x, y)-coordinates of the circle origin...
        center = vertices;
    }
    else if (shapeType==2) //shape is a triangle
    {
        numVertices = 3; 
    }
}


std::list<Shape> shapeList;
void my_display(void) 
{
  /* clear the buffer */
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


  //altFlag is just a value to allow alternating between rectangles/circles being printed

  if (altFlag==1)
  {
      printf("Drawing rectangle at: (%g, %g)\n", my_x, my_y);

      /*instantiate a Shape() object representing a blue rectangle*/
      int rgbColor[3] = {0, 0, 1};

      double vertices[4] = {my_x/window_w, my_y/window_h, my_x/window_w + my_rect_w, my_y/window_h + my_rect_h};

      Shape my_rectangle(0, vertices, rgbColor); //uses constructor (shape type, list of vertex coordinates, length of coordinate list, color)

      glColor3f((GLfloat)my_rectangle.rgb[0], (GLfloat)my_rectangle.rgb[1], (GLfloat)my_rectangle.rgb[2]) ; /* (Red, Green, Blue); so here we ask for Blue */
      glRectf(my_rectangle.vertexArray[0], my_rectangle.vertexArray[1], my_rectangle.vertexArray[2], my_rectangle.vertexArray[3]); //call to function to draw a rectangle
      altFlag=0;

      shapeList.push_front(my_rectangle);
  }
  else
  {
      /*instantiate a Shape() object representing a red circle*/
      int circleColor[3] = {1, 0, 0};
      double circleCenter[2] = {(my_x), (my_y)}; //{center x coord, center y coord}
      //Shape* my_circle = new Shape(1, circleCenter, circleColor); 
      Shape my_circle(1, circleCenter, circleColor);

      glColor3f(my_circle.rgb[0], my_circle.rgb[1], my_circle.rgb[2]);
      glCirclef(my_circle.center[0], my_circle.center[1]); //call to function to draw pseudocircle

      altFlag=1;

      shapeList.push_front(my_circle);
  }

  //iterate over shapeList, print out values of the rgb array.
  for (std::list<Shape>::iterator iter = shapeList.begin(); iter != shapeList.end(); iter++)
  {
      printf("%d, %d, %d\n", iter->rgb[0], iter->rgb[1], iter->rgb[2]);
  }

  glutSwapBuffers();

  return;
```

While this is part of an assignment, the question pertains to the language being used, as opposed to the graphics library which is the focus of the course.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Shape` and its member functions (at least the constructor).

Comment: You've been writing too much Java. There are so many memory management mistakes in that code that it's impossible to point them all out. At the very least, use `std::vector` for your arrays.

Comment: I completely agree; I wish C++ was taught in more classes. Alas, this is how I must learn. The embarrassing mistakes of today will become invaluable lessons for tomorrow.

Comment: Hint: use inline code formatting (backtick marks) to prevent the display "eating" angle brackets, as I did in editing your question; it makes the post even more readable.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I took this course because it's literally the only one that uses mostly C++. The game dev graphics stuff is just a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameterised constructor of `Shape` does this:

```
vertexArray = vertices;
```

Where `vertices` is a function parameter declared as `double vertices[]`. This is syntactic sugar to `double *vertices`, i.e., you're copying a *pointer* (because arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions).

`vertexArray` is defined as a pointer inside the class. You even mention it's a "dynamic array," but then you initialise it with an array allocated on the stack (a local variable inside `display()`). This makes the pointer dangling.

You will have to make `vertexArray` an array and copy the data, not just the pointer. Something like this:

```
class Shape
{
  // ...
  double vertexArray[4];
  // ...
};

Shape::Shape(int shapeType, double vertices[], int color[])
{
    type = shapeType;

    if (shapeType==0) //shape is a rectangle
    {
        numVertices = 4;
    }
    else if(shapeType==1) //shape is a circle
    {
        //shape is a circle, therefore the second array param is in fact an array of size 2 containing the (x, y)-coordinates of the circle origin...
        center = vertices;
    }
    else if (shapeType==2) //shape is a triangle
    {
        numVertices = 3; 
    }

    if (shapeType!=1) //as long as shape is NOT a circle, interpret the second constructor parameter as a list of vertices 
    {
        std::copy(vertices, vertices + numVertices, vertexArray);
    }
}
```

And analogically for `color` as well, of course.

**Extra suggestions**

Of course, this code would be much better using `std::vector` or something similar instead of plain arrays, using and `enum` instead of `int` for `shapeType` etc. I suggest you pick up a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed feedback! I'm off to class but will look at this in detail within the hour.

Comment: You have helped SO MUCH! In addition to opening my eyes in the direction of my (now obviously foolish) mistake, you showed me a fantastic STL copy algorithm for future use.